# How to do UNIX Shell Programming on a Windows PC with no UNIX?

Tags: windows, shell, unix

I have a PC which has Windows 7. I dont have any Hard Drive with UNIX O/S. Is it possible to do UNIX Shell Programming on this PC without UNIX installed on it? If yes please tell me the steps.

Thanks

Comment: Use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, however I want to share some experience: I have written win Batch on my linux box with vim.. it was really painful!  Editing was okay, but testing.....  I had to check each single command help on a win machine, because I don't know Win so much..... Writing the simple script took 2 days, which I can do it in 10 min with shellscript....  So... try to get a test server or install a virtual machine/start a docker for your development.

Comment: Install VirtualBox for free and then have as many different linux machines as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can found what you're looking for at :
http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/

There is an installation explanation on the website.

Comment: to get a true unix environment you might install virtualbox and install linux on that.